# How do I auto scroll through tabs with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below code to click through a number of tabs. However, is there a way to get the tabs to automatically change as well every 4 seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
    });

});
```

Comment: How do you want the tabs to change? Are you trying to do a Carousel ( http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Carousel ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Make it into a nice function;

```
function changeTabs(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
}
```

A javascript timer that calls the function;

```
setInterval(function(){ changeTabs(); }, 4000);
```

Then you can always keep your click one as well;

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
    changeTabs();
});
```

Comment: What about the `this` in the function...?

Comment: I think he wanted every 4 seconds so you should use setInterval. Also, not sure your changeTabs will work because $(this) doesn't actually point to any tabs when you are cycling through them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setInverval` function which will execute a function repeatedly after waiting for a given amount of time.

Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

The difference between `setInterval` and `setTimeout` is that `setInterval` will execute a block of code every, say X, seconds. `setTimeout`, however, will execute the code and then wait X seconds before executing the code again and resetting the delay.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` for each tab it will be activated.

```
$.each($('ul.tabs li'), function(i, el){

   setTimeout(
   function() 
   {
   //wait for tabs then go
   }, 0+(i*4000));
   // start turn
   setInterval(function(){
       var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
       $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
       $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
       $(this).addClass('current');
       $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
   },4000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

You could do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var lis = $('ul.tabs li');
   var tab_id = 1;
   var changeTab = function(){
      console.log(tab_id);
      $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
      $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
          
      $("#" + tab_id).parent().addClass('current');
      tab_id=tab_id%lis.length + 1;
  }
      
  var intervalID = window.setInterval(changeTab, 4000);
});
```

```css
.current{
  display: block !important;
}
ul.tabs li{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="current"><span id="1" class="tab-content">111111</span></li>
      <li><span id="2" class="tab-content">222222</span></li>
      <li><span id="3" class="tab-content">333333</span></li>
    </ul>
```